# the dialog cannot be opened for the following reason: No column in spec compatible to 'DoubleValue'

Tags: knime

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7wOh.png)
I encountered an error when passing data from a table to the Linear Regression Learner function. Could you please help me resolve this issue?

I tried looking for a function that can convert a number from "Number to Double" in KNIME, but couldn't find anything. I also attempted to convert it to a string, but that didn't work either. I don't understand why it's giving me such a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

What's the original data type? I notice you said "Number to Double"; when you say number, do you mean Int?

In order to avoid any issues, I would look at the node where the data is being generated. If, for example, you are using the "Column Expression" node to generate the numbers, then set the data type to "Number (Double)" in there.

You can also use the Column Expression node to convert the data type.